# Need help translating java program to C

Tags: java, c

This program does the division for very large numbers (i need it just up to 1000 digits). because no data type can handle very large numbers we use arrays.
I'm trying to translate this Java program to C. I have done some of it but having troubles converting strings to a C compatible data type. remember we need to take numbers as string then convert to int.

**the biggest challenge seems to be String, StringBuilder and append.** i have no idea how to translate these.

having most trouble with:

```
if (len1 < len2) return new String[]{"0", n1};
          StringBuilder digits = new StringBuilder();
          String n3 = n1.substring(0, len2);
```

Java code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


class BigDiv
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      String n1 = "30";
      String n2 = "2";
      String[] results = Divide(n1, n2);
      System.out.println("Quotient is  : " + results[0]);
      System.out.println("Remainder is : " + results[1]);
   }

   static String[] Divide(String n1, String n2)
   {
      Boolean negative = false;
      if (n1.charAt(0) == '-' ^ n2.charAt(0) == '-') negative = true;
      if (n1.charAt(0) == '-') n1 = n1.substring(1);
      if (n2.charAt(0) == '-') n2 = n2.substring(1);
      if (n1.equals("0") && n2.equals("0"))
      {
         return new String[] {"Not a number", "0"};
      }

      if (n2.equals("0"))
      {
         if (!negative) return new String[] {"Infinity", "0"};
         return new String[] {"-Infinity", "0"};
      }

      int len1 = n1.length();
      int len2 = n2.length();
      if (len1 < len2) return new String[]{"0", n1};
      StringBuilder digits = new StringBuilder();
      String n3 = n1.substring(0, len2);
      int len3 = len2;
      String n4;
      int quotient; 
      int index = len2 - 1;

      while(true)
      {
         quotient = 0;

         while(true)
         {
            n4 = Subtract(n3, n2);  

            if (n4 == "-1") 
            {
               break;
            } 

            quotient++;

            //System.out.println(quotient);

            if (n4 == "0")
            { 
               n3 = "0";
               break;
            }

            n3 = n4;
         }

         if (digits.toString().equals("0"))
         {
             digits.setCharAt(0, (char)(quotient + 48));
         } 
         else
         {
             digits.append((char)(quotient + 48));   
         }

         if (index < len1 - 1)
         { 
            index++;
            if (n3.equals("0")) n3 = "";
            n3 += n1.charAt(index);
            len3 = n3.length();
         }
         else
         {
            String result = new String(digits); 
            if (negative)
            {
               if (!result.equals("0")) result = "-" + result;
               if (!n3.equals("0")) n3 = "-" + n3;
            }
            return new String[]{result, n3}; 

         }                        
      }   
   }          

   static String Subtract(String n1, String n2)
   {
      int len1 = n1.length();
      int len2 = n2.length(); 
      if (len1 < len2) return "-1";
      int max = Math.max(len1, len2);
      int[] ia1 = new int[max];
      int[] ia2 = new int[max];
      int[] ia3 = new int[max];
      for(int i = max - len1; i < max; i++) ia1[i] = n1.charAt(i + len1 - max) - 48;
      for(int i = max - len2; i < max; i++) ia2[i] = n2.charAt(i + len2 - max) - 48;
      int diff = 0;
      int carry = 0;


      for(int i = max - 1; i >= 0; i--)
      {
         diff = ia1[i] - ia2[i] - carry;
         carry = 0;
         if (diff < 0)
         {
            diff += 10;
            carry = 1;
         } 
         ia3[i] = diff;
      }

      if (carry == 1) return "-1";

      // find first non-zero element of array ia3
      int first = -1;
      for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
      {
         if (ia3[i] != 0)
         {
            first = i;
            break;
         }
      }

      if (first == -1) first = max - 1;
      char[] c3 = new char[max - first];
      for(int i = first; i < max; i++) c3[i - first] = (char)(ia3[i] + 48);
      //System.out.println("c IS : " + c3[0]);
      return new String(c3);       
   }
```

my C code so far: (in divide function there is a check for NaN and Negative numbers which i don't really need. also i should not use VLA.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

    int Divide(char n1[], char n2[]);
    int Subtract(char n1[], char n2[]);

    int main()
    {
      char n1[] = "30";
      char n2[] = "2";
      char results[] = Divide(n1, n2);
      printf("Quotient is  : %d", results[0]);
      printf("Remainder is : %d", results[1]);
    }

    int Divide(char n1[], char n2[])
    {
      /*Boolean negative = false;
      if (n1[0] == '-' ^ n2[0] == '-') negative = true;
      if (n1[0] == '-') n1 = n1.substring(1);
      if (n2[0] == '-') n2 = n2.substring(1);
      if (n1.equals("0") && n2.equals("0"))
      {
         return new String[] {"Not a number", "0"};
      }

      if (n2.equals("0"))
      {
         if (!negative) return new String[] {"Infinity", "0"};
         return new String[] {"-Infinity", "0"};
      }*/

      int len1 = strlen(n1);
      int len2 = strlen(n2);
      if (len1 < len2) return new String[]{"0", n1};
      StringBuilder digits = new StringBuilder();
      String n3 = n1.substring(0, len2);
      int len3 = len2;
      String n4;
      int quotient;
      int index = len2 - 1;

      while(true)
      {
         quotient = 0;

         while(true)
         {
            n4 = Subtract(n3, n2);

            if (n4 == "-1")
            {
               break;
            }

            quotient++;

            if (n4 == "0")
            {
               n3 = "0";
               break;
            }

            n3 = n4;
         }

         if (digits.toString().equals("0"))
         {
             digits.setCharAt(0, (char)(quotient + 48));
         }
         else
         {
             digits.append((char)(quotient + 48));
         }

         if (index < len1 - 1)
         {
            index++;
            if (n3.equals("0")) n3 = "";
            n3 += n1[index];
            len3 = n3.length();
         }
         else
         {
            String result = new String(digits);
            if (negative)
            {
               if (!result.equals("0")) result = "-" + result;
               if (!n3.equals("0")) n3 = "-" + n3;
            }
            return new String[]{result, n3};

         }
      }
    }

    int Subtract(char n1[], char n2[])
    {
      int len1 = n1.length();
      int len2 = n2.length();
      if (len1 < len2) return "-1";
      int max;

      if(len1>len2) max = len1;
      else if(len2>len1) max = len2;
      else max = len1;

      int ia1[max];
      int ia2[max];
      int ia3[max];
      for(int i = max - len1; i < max; i++) ia1[i] = n1[i + len1 - max] - 48;
      for(int i = max - len2; i < max; i++) ia2[i] = n2[i + len2 - max] - 48;
      int diff = 0;
      int carry = 0;


      for(int i = max - 1; i >= 0; i--)
      {
         diff = ia1[i] - ia2[i] - carry;
         carry = 0;
         if (diff < 0)
         {
            diff += 10;
            carry = 1;
         }
         ia3[i] = diff;
      }

      if (carry == 1) return "-1";

      // find first non-zero element of array ia3
      int first = -1;
      for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
      {
         if (ia3[i] != 0)
         {
            first = i;
            break;
         }
      }

      if (first == -1) first = max - 1;
      char c3[max - first];
      for(int i = first; i < max; i++) c3[i - first] = (char)(ia3[i] + 48);
      return new String(c3);
    }
```

Comment: Do not do that, translating a program in that direction will not work, because of the programming languages are too different, I suggest to rewrite the program, using a design that suites the language.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? Where are you facing difficulties?

Comment: StringBuilder and append also return

Comment: Besides actually *learning* C, a [good reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c) might become handy.

Comment: I know C but need some extra help on this.

Comment: I didn't ask for code guys, just some advice...

Comment: @vvvsg: I would recommend including your problem in the question (in a question format)

Comment: @vvvsg You say you know C, but, sorry, you do `return new String[]{result, n3};`

Comment: @Mr Lister  I didn't change that part because i don't know how to...

Comment: @MrLister also that is a comment

Comment: @vvvsg Sorry, I copied the wrong line, but you also have the same in an uncommented block.

Comment: @vvvsg You have to translate your program *figuratively*, not *literally*. If it helps you, write down what your Java program does, step by step, in plain English. Then hide your java code and follow the text you just wrote to implement the same program in C.

Comment: @Siguza I actually tried that but had no luck, that's why I'm doing this... maybe someone can help me with those Strings...

Comment: @vvvsg Then reduce your question to the problematic passage.

Comment: first of all you need to learn C.

Answer (score 0):

Strings in C are simply sequences of characters terminated by a 0-valued byte.  There is no dedicated string type; they are stored as arrays of `char`, and operators such as `=`, `+`, and `==` are not defined for arrays.

To assign strings, use the [`strcpy`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcpy.html) library function.  To append strings to each other, you use the [`strcat`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcat.html) library function.  To compare strings, use [`strcmp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcmp.html).

You must do your own memory management; C will not automatically allocate more memory as you extend a string, nor will it do any automatic garbage collection when there are no more references to that memory, meaning you must explicitly deallocate any dynamically allocated memory.  Use [`malloc`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/fhttp://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcmp.html/malloc.html) or [`calloc`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/calloc.html) to allocate memory, [`realloc`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/realloc.html) to allocate or extend a buffer that's been allocated with `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc`, and [`free`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/free.html) to deallocate memory that was allocated with `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc`.

`malloc` does not initialize the dynamically-allocated memory; `calloc` will initialize it to all-bits-0.

Here's some sample C code that will allocate, assign, append, compare, and deallocate a string:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define INITIAL_SIZE 20

int main( void )
{
  /**
   * Allocate space to store a string; the +1 is to make sure
   * we have space for the 0 terminator.
   */
  char *str1 = calloc( INITIAL_SIZE+1, sizeof *str1 ); 
  size_t str1size = INITIAL_SIZE + 1;

  /**
   * str2 will point to a string literal; literals are stored as
   * arrays of char such that they are allocated at program startup
   * and held until the program terminates.  String literals may
   * not be modified, so we're declaring the pointer as const char *.
   */
  const char *str2 = " of the Emergency Broadcast System";

  /**
   * Copy a string to that buffer
   */
  strcpy( str1, "This is a test" );

  /**
   * Extend the buffer to hold more stuff; typical strategy is
   * to double the buffer size each time.  For this particular
   * example this loop should only run once.  
   */
  while ( strlen( str1 ) + strlen( str2 ) > str1size)
  {
    char *tmp = realloc( str1, 2 * str1size );
    if ( !tmp )
    {
       // realloc failed, for this example we treat it as a fatal error
       exit( -1 );
    }
    str1 = tmp;
    str1size *= 2;
  }

  /**
   * Append to the buffer
   */
  strcat( str1, str2 );

  // do something interesting with str1 here

  /**
   * Deallocate the buffer
   */
  free( str1 );

  return 0;
}
```

You *must* make sure your target buffer is large enough to hold whatever you're writing to it.  C doesn't do bounds checking on array accesses, and it won't throw an exception if you try to read or write outside of the array bounds (unless you're trying to access protected memory, but that's a system exception, not a language exception).